# c# windows service - check network folder exists

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service running as local system, which will search for some files / folders in specified locations.

The problem is when i specify the Path to a Shared folder in Network it will return "Path Not Found"

i have set

```
serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

but i tried `ServiceAccount.NetworkService` by setting `UserName` and `Password` using `this.Context.Parameters[key].ToString()`

at this time nothing happens

for `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` if i set "Log On" property through "Services.msc" it will work fine.  but need it to achieve through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your service under a user account that has rights to the network volumes. Typically this means one of your domain accounts. None of the built in service accounts will have such rights.

Comment: ++ to what David said.

If the machines are in the same domain, have a service account setup that grants you permission and set the service to run as this account. Why do you need to achieve this configuration through code?

Comment: @David. i agree with you. but is there any way to get the logged in user account details and set that info via code. my user(s) has right to network volumes

Comment: @Khepri. the user may not know the service account info. so need to set it through code. and the end user just need to install the service.

Comment: @binil you can't get the logged in user's password

Comment: @David any links for using `ServiceAccount.NetworkService`. i searched a lot. but didnt find any examples.

Comment: @binil `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` won't have rights to the volumes. You need a domain user.